# Was offered the job, but asked for more money and haven't heard back

Tags: job-change

I am at the location where I would end up working if I took the job, leaving tomorrow morning. I was offered the job 2 days ago, and asked for more money yesterday. My future boss and his boss said they would need to get approval but I haven't heard back from them. 
Should I follow up with an email? If so, what do I say?

Comment: Your first sentence is confusing.  What do you mean by "at the location... if I took the job" and "leaving tomorrow morning".  Where are you going tomorrow?

Comment: @MikeP: I too was confused by that sentence, but I worked it out in the end. It means: "Until tomorrow morning, I am in the town/city where I would be relocating to if I got the job." So they have probably just attended a job interview there.

Comment: I would have thought that they would need a few days at least. Also do not put all your eggs in one basket

Answer (score 1):

Asking for approval for potential over-budget salary is quite common. It may take few days for them to consider it. Always ask how much time they need to consider your application - I always get some approximate date.
Assuming you are working in some country with Monday to Friday working days, contact them not earlier than Monday afternoon. 2-3 days for them is minimum.
If you need response before some specific time, always ask in advance if they are able to provide it to you.

Comment: Even Monday afternoon is too soon. I would give them a week. In other words: it's too soon to worry, lauraoc!